# What is the difference between using the friend keyword, and using a member function to modify private variables inside of a class?

Tags: c++

As the question asks...

What is the difference between:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(){
        m_a = 0;
    }
private:
    int m_a;
    friend void set_a(MyClass &a);
};


void set_a(MyClass &a)
{
    std::cout << a.m_a << std::endl;
    a.m_a = 500;
    std::cout << a.m_a << std::endl;
}



int main(void) {
    MyClass my_class_instance;
    set_a(my_class_instance);

    system("pause");
}
```

and:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(){
        m_a = 0;
    }
    void set_a(){
        std::cout << this->m_a << std::endl;
        this->m_a = 500;
        std::cout << this->m_a << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int m_a;
};



int main(void) {
    MyClass my_class_instance;
    my_class_instance.set_a();

    system("pause");
}
```

Is it simply the preferred structure of the function, or are there real, measurable differences? From what I can tell, both functions achieve the same results in all circumstances, except if you had multiple overloads for the first example, that took different types of objects.

Comment: In the first case, by putting the keyword `friend` in front of void set_a() you have turned set_a() into a non-member function. In the second case, your set_a() function is a member function, i.e. it is MyClass::set_a().  So that's one difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the C++ FAQ says](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/member-vs-friend-fns.html): **Use a member when you can, and a friend when you have to.**

There are situations where making `friend` a free function is preferable, most situations related to the fact that **the first parameter of a member function is always of that class** (Its the hidden `*this` parameter).

One example is arithmetic operators overloading:
Suppose you write a `complex` class which represents complex numbers. Using a member `operator+()` you could write expressions like `complex + float`, but not  `float + complex`. But you could do it with the free form of the `operator+`:

```
class complex
{
    ...
    friend complex operator+( float f , complex c );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This whole question comes down to "Why would I use friends in C++?". The answer is that when used properly, friends enhance encapsulation. This is an FAQ:

[Do friends violate encapsulation?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/friends-and-encap.html)

Your example is too short and too abstract, of course. Some better, real life examples I could think of from the top of my head involve iterators. You may have *many iterator objects* referring to only *one container object*, and you may want the iterator to be able to access private member variables of the container. At the same time, you don't want the container to expose those variables to the rest of the world.

Such a design could be perfectly implemented with the `friend` feature.

Comment: Two entries bellow, there is exactly this same question, and the proper answer: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/member-vs-friend-fns.html

Comment: Right. Good old FAQ :)

Answer (score 0):

Many people defend that making accessor methods, you can in a later stage of development put barriers to the incorrect access to the member variables (or even change the member variables totally) without breaking your (correct) clients.

One classical case is of a

```
class ComplexNumber {
  double real, imaginary;
public:
  double re() { return re; }
  double setRe(double v) { return re = v; }
// and so on ...
};
```

one day you discover, in some maintenance, that you need the polar coordinates for that number, so you add the methods

```
  double rho() { /* calculate rho */ }
  double theta() { /* calculate theta */ }
  double setRho(double v) { /* calculate real, imaginary, based on the new rho */ }
```

and so on.

Later yet, you discover that the users of the class use far more often polar than Cartesian coordinates for complex numbers, and that *the conversions have been the bottleneck of a performance problem*, so you ditch `real` and `imaginary` and store `rho` and `theta`,  and change the getter and setter methods for the new -- more efficient -- storage for `rho`, `theta`, `re`, `im`, and so on. All the clients of your class will recompile without problems, because you changed your implementation but kept your interfaces stable.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this is related. Can you please elaborate? From what I can see, you can use both member functions and friend functions for this.

Comment: I don't see what are you trying to demostrate, but what I see is a bad get/set pattern which breaks the point of encapsulation.

Comment: @Massa: friends give you exactly the same encapsulation. You should view friends more like a 4th level of member functions (in addition to private, protected and public).